# Re-execute React Effect on URL change for Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, react-hooks

I am using React in a Chrome Extension where the extension's `content.js` loads the `index.html` of the compiled React app.

In the React app, an effect prints out the current tab's domain in the JS console when the app first loads, due to having a dependency of `[]`.

```js
function App() {
    useEffect(() => {
        chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, (tabs) => {
            const url = new URL(tabs[0].url);
            const domain = url.hostname;
            console.log("Domain:", domain);
        });
    }, []);

    ...
}
```

Is it possible to modify this such that the effect is executed again everytime the tab is navigated to another URL?

Answer (score 0):

You should subscribe to `chrome.tabs` changes:

```js
function App() {
    useEffect(() => {
        chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(queryTabs)
    }, []);
    

const queryTabs = (id, info, tab) => {
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, (tabs) => {
            // Do something with tabs
            const url = new URL(tabs[0].url);
            const domain = url.hostname;
            console.log("Domain:", domain);
        });
}
    ...
}
```

You have a lot of tab events that you can subscribe to, I chose `update` for sake of simplicity:

- onActivated
- onActiveChanged
- onAttached
- onCreated
- onDetached
- onHighlightChanged
- onHighlighted
- onMoved
- onRemoved
- onReplaced
- onSelectionChanged
- onUpdated
- onZoomChange

you might want to find what suits your case better by checking chrome [DOCS](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#event-onUpdated).